# Android resource linking failed in Floating Action button

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

Android resource linking failed: 208

208 ->

```
  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_Gravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/gridLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gridLayout" />
```

build.gradle :->

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

Comment: `app:layout_Gravity` – That attribute doesn't exist. Did you mean to set that value in `android:layout_gravity` (note the lowercase `g`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
android:layout_gravity = "bottom|right|end"
```

Thanks